# Failure in create signed driver by Microsoft

Tags: .net, windows-10, digital-signature, drivers

I'm trying to build a dummy driver and sign it using the following formal example from [microsoft official webpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn800660(v=vs.85).aspx) .

in phase 3 on the attached document, I suppose to run some `.net` code that include the following command method:

```
static HttpResponseMessage SendRequest(HttpRequestMessage message)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Sending request to " + message.RequestUri);
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //Trace.WriteLine("Set Bearer header to " + AuthToken);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthToken);

        var resp = client.SendAsync(message).Result;
        if(resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return resp;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException("The request failed with status code response: " + resp.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

However, it fails because the variable `AuthToken` is undefined.

I wish to understand what is the purpose of AuthToken and how should I defined it to be used in this code.

Comment: Programing questions are not on topic here at Superuser.  I have voted to migrate this to Stackoverflow.  Do NOT delete this question, it will be moved to the correct community, once enough people vote to migrate it.  I suggest once its been migrated. you pick better tags, because they don't have anything to do with your question.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I had thoughts about which forum this question will fit exactly, and eventually i've decided to put it here as it mainly involve windows remote driver signature. the code snippet I've added is provided by microsoft and only meant to emphasis where exactly i've failed in the process. there's no programming concepts here, but pure knowledge about how to sign drivers in windows-10-v1607.

Comment: StackExchange websites *are not* forums.

Comment: "but pure knowledge about how to sign drivers in windows-10-v1607" - If thats the case, your question isn't clear, That isn't clear.  Of course I would argue that, if its not working, it is INDEED a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor signature of AuthenticationValueHeader shows that it's expecting AuthToken to be a string. 
Step 2 of the document you reference describes how to retrieve the authentication token string. You just need to manually add (copy and paste) it to the code in step 3.

Comment: many thanks for the help, perhaps do you know more about some other missing methods i've encountered : GetFirstGuidFromUrl and TimeAction ?

Comment: I'd start new questions regarding those other missing methods. They'll get more exposure than these comments and follow on questions are discouraged on here. Also, if my answer successfully answered the original question, could you accept it as such please?

Comment: if you're familiar with the whole process of signing, please refer to my other question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376213/create-signed-driver-by-microsoft-getfirstguidfromurl-and-timeaction-are-missi